# Memset a buffer shared by two processes

Tags: c++, multithreading, fork, ipc, shared-memory

Lets say I have a buffer class and it has a member variable char* where data will be written and read. `data` member is allocated in shared memory.

```
class Buffer{
  char* data;
}
```

I also have two independent processes each with it's own instance of buffer. One process writing to the buffer and the other reading from it.

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid ==0){
  auto buffer = Buffer();
} else{
  auto buffer = Buffer();
}
```

Question: How can I do `memset(data_, 0, size)`? I want it done so that the reader does not get rubbish values from the buffer, and should ideally only be done once.

I've tried using `boost::interprocess::named_mutex`, but it's really slow. I benchmarked it.

My solution (in the constructor of buffer):

```
mutex.lock()
if (data_[0]!='X'){
    memset(data+1,0,size);
    data[0] = 'X';
}
mutex.unlock()
```

Basically just checking and setting the first byte of the buffer.

Comment: The usual solution would be to zero out the memory, then fork.

Comment: Mutex might be slow because the other process has to get a time slice to see a change there?  Not going to make it any slower than normal in that case.  You could open a socket between the two processes and communicate that way.  Is the mutex so slow it would affect your performance negatively?

Comment: @Pete Yes I benchmarked it and it adds about 600ns to the timing. Not sure why it's so slow though. Thought it would be faster.

Comment: Sorry should have added that I'm using fork to simulate to different independent programs accessing the buffer at the same time @MooingDuck so zeroing the memory outside the fork wouldn't be right

Comment: @user3702643: If reading processes can access the buffer before its zeroed out, then they will always read invalid data and the problem cannot be fixed.  Period.

Comment: 600 nano seconds too slow for you?  That's incredibly fast imo.  Why would that even be noticeable for your application?

Comment: How are you intending to share the mapping ultimately then? Either one process requests an FD from the other over IPC (in which case the server can zero the mapping), or it's file-backed, or ... what?

Answer (score 0):

Have each process lock the named mutex once at process startup, so it it can verify that the buffer is initialized, and safely initialize it if it isn’t.  Then unlock the mutex, and from them on the process can access the buffer without locking the mutex because it knows for certain the buffer is already initialized.  (Of course you might find you have other problems accessing the data within the buffer safely, if other processes might be concurrently modifying it, but that’s a different issue)